# Sed usage to eliminate characters around certain patterns but not others

Tags: bash, unix, syntax, sed

I have a file with thousands of lines marked similar to this:

{3203}

{1293}

{xii}

{xi}

{vii}

etc...

I need to eliminate the brackets around the **numbers** but not the letters (roman numerals) so in essence it would look like

3203

1293

{xii}

{xi}

{vii}

etc..

I would put up what I've been testing so far, but I'm not especially close to getting any part of the sed statement correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be close to what you are looking for:

```
sed -e 's/{\([0-9]\+\)}/\1/g' inputfile
```

Comment: Does sed not have the \d character class? That may be why mine wasn't working.

Comment: @Dan:  I'm not actually sure ... sed regex syntax *always* messes me up.  For example, I just now changed it to use `\+` (one or more).  I initially used `*` because my `+` without the preceding backslash was not matching.

Comment: That seems to do it.  Thanks Mark!

Comment: Deleted mine and upvoted yours - you changed from `*` to `\+` as I was posting. @roger34 - note too that you don't need the `/g` global match if all your lines have only one number on them.

Comment: Sneaky. I'll leave my Perl solution up because it's pretty much just as easy, and may have more familiar regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to work with sed, but this works if you have Perl available:

```
perl -pe 's/{(\d+)}/\1/' inputfile
```